# How to create a User Interface in Xamarin.Forms using JSON Element

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs

How to create a User Interface in Xamarin.Forms using a JSON Element?

I have two json files and I'd like to create a dynamic UI using json elements in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Do you actually have a question?  Just stating "I want X" is not the way to ask something on SO.

Comment: I have update the question, Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this

```
StackLayout stack = new StackLayout();

// controls is an collection of control definitions built from your json
foreach(var c in controls)
{
  if (c.Type == "Button") {
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Text = c.Text;
    stack.Add(button);
  }

  if (c.Type == "Label") {
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text = c.Text;
    stack.Add(label);
  }

  // repeat for each supported type of control
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason for helping.

Comment: I have a second Rest API which is having the data that I need to fill into the above dynamic controls, How I can achieve that

Comment: Combine the lists before you start.  Or make a 2nd pass to add data.  Or use data binding.  There are multiple ways to approach it, without knowing a lot more detail it's hard to say which would work best.

Comment: I have created dynamic controls Every button click its create duplicate control. How to clean controls.